# Custom style sheet in Azure won't work, but works fine on local machine

Tags: css, razor-pages

I made a style sheet called customStyles.css, I referenced it from my _Layout.cshtml, and used it
in my index page. It works fine on my local machine but will not render my styles when I publish it
to Azure. What am I doing wrong?
The file's location in the solution explorer:

[image: my style sheet's location in the solution]
In the head of my layout page I have this:

```
<environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/customStyles.css"/>
    </environment>
```

And where I reference the class in the stylesheet, in my Index Page:

```
<div class="startIndexTable" style="margin-left:150px; margin-right:600px;">
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>  ...etc...
```

I also added the styles directly into my  tag, which works. But, of course,
I am not satisfied with this type of hard-coding.

Comment: did you check if the stylesheet is in the `environment` you use in Azure? [see this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The `include` attribute of the [environment tag helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/environment-tag-helper) specifies the environment(s) in which the content is rendered. Since you only specify that the style sheets should be included within the `Development` environment, they will not be included in production i.e when the application is published.

If you intend assets to be rendered/referenced in all environments, don't use the environment tag helper.

Comment: I plopped my link tag out of the <environments include="development"> tag but still within the <head> tag and it seems to work fine. I had previously included my link tag inside the <environments exclude="development"> tag but it threw a 502 error. Also, the documentation link above was helpful to broader  environments issue.